# I want to send my sensor data from Arduino UNO to Firebase database. I am getting this error, is there any other method I can do this?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino

This is my code in arduino IDE:

Header files:

```
#include <Firebase.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#include <FirebaseCloudMessaging.h>
#include <FirebaseError.h>
#include <FirebaseHttpClient.h>
#include <FirebaseObject.h>
```

Code to connect to wifi:

```
#define FIREBASE_HOST "fir-app-example.firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "examplesd2asdasdasdasd2asd3asd2asd2as32das3d2as2da3"
#define WIFI_SSID "abcd"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "123456"
#define LED 13

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED,0);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("connected: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
  Firebase.setInt("LEDStatus",0);
}
```

Here I am using my Firebase Database:

```
void loop() {
  if(Firebase.getInt("LEDStatus")) {
    digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
  }
  if (Firebase.failed()) // Check for errors {
    Serial.print("setting /number failed:");
    Serial.println(Firebase.error());
    return;
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

Error:
I'm constantly getting this error

```
arduino-builder/arduino-builder -compile -core-api-version 10611 -build-path /tmp/808655269 -hardware arduino-builder/hardware -hardware arduino-builder/packages/cores -tools arduino-builder/tools -tools arduino-builder/packages/tools -built-in-libraries arduino-builder/latest -libraries /tmp/608097246/pinned -libraries /tmp/608097246/custom -fqbn arduino:avr:uno -build-cache /tmp -verbose=false /tmp/608097246/Firebase

In file included from /tmp/608097246/Firebase/Firebase.ino:1:0:

/tmp/608097246/custom/firebase-arduino/src/Firebase.h:24:18: fatal error: memory: No such file or directory

#include <memory>
^
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
```

I referred to this link:

http://www.devacron.com/arduino-firebase/

My Board: Arduino Uno+ESP8266

Answer (score 3):

From https://github.com/firebase/firebase-arduino:

> an Arduino library that show how to call the Firebase API from the [ESP8266 Arduino core](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino).

This library is written only for use when directly programming an ESP8266 using the mentioned Arduino core, which contains the missing file.

Although you are using an ESP8266 in your project, you are attempting to compile and upload code to the Arduino Uno, not the ESP8266. It is not possible to use this library with your current hardware configuration.

Possible solutions:

- Directly program the ESP8266. This could also allow you to not use the Arduino Uno at all in your project.
- Find a library that allows you to use the Firebase API from your Arduino Uno or write your own code for this. It may be that the limited resources of the Arduino Uno are not sufficient for this.

Answer (score 0):

Proper code indentation shows where your bug is:

```
  if (Firebase.failed()) // Check for errors {
```

Your opening `{` is commented out... Change that to:

```
  if (Firebase.failed()) {
    // Check for errors
```

And it should compile.